# Why "=" and "LIKE" behave the opposite way they should?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I discovered a problem on my procedure and finally the problem was found. When trying to ask documents with configuration name 'Default' these two queries give two different results:

```
SELECT DC.ConfigurationName, DC.ConfigurationID
FROM DocumentConfiguration DC
WHERE DC.ConfigurationName='Default'
```

Results:

| ConfigurationName | ConfigurationID |
| --- | --- |
| Default | 1 |
| Default | 2 |

That lower 'Default' has a trailing space, ASCII character 32.

This query gives only the exact result I needed:

```
SELECT DC.ConfigurationName, DC.ConfigurationID
FROM DocumentConfiguration DC
WHERE DC.ConfigurationName LIKE 'Default'
```

Results:

| ConfigurationName | ConfigurationID |
| --- | --- |
| Default | 1 |

I understood = should give only the exact match while LIKE should be used with wildcards. Why those two queries seem to work the opposite of how they should?

I fixed the procedure so that it now uses LIKE instead of = and the whole procedure works correctly. I did not expect this to work, because = should only give an exact match.

Comment: *"MS SQL Server 19"* Unlikely; Version 16 (2022) only came out last year.

Comment: As for why, Trailing spaces are ignored for comparison purposes in SQL; this is an ANSI thing, it's not unique to T-SQL.

Comment: Trailing spaces are ignored on string equality checks. It is well documented.

Comment: Though, I can't replicate your behaviour. **Both** queries return both rows. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AWtG_hC0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you have trailing spaces on the end of one of the values. When this happens, the `=` operator treats them both as matches, and the `like` operator does not, per ANSI standards according the docs.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-comparison-assignment?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks

> The SQL Server Database Engine follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92
> specification (Section 8.2, Comparison Predicate, General rules #3) on
> how to compare strings with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding
> for the character strings used in comparisons so that their lengths
> match before comparing them. The padding directly affects the
> semantics of WHERE and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL
> string comparisons. **For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings
> 'abc' and 'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations**. **The
> only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate. When the right side
> of a LIKE predicate expression features a value with a trailing space,
> the Database Engine doesn't pad the two values to the same length
> before the comparison occurs.** Because the purpose of the LIKE
> predicate, by definition, is to facilitate pattern searches rather
> than simple string equality tests, this predicate doesn't violate the
> section of the ANSI SQL-92 specification mentioned earlier.

The table column data type (`nvarchar` vs `varchar`) also impacts the results when using the `LIKE` operator (tested in SQL 2014 and SQL 2022).

Below are results of a [test query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/53ccf/2) with various filters using `nvarchar` vs `varchar`, where each row represent the results for the where clause applied against a table with 'Default' and 'Default ' values.

Notice how test case "3. nvarchar like 'Default'" (row 5) only returns one match, but test case "7. varchar like 'Default'" (rows 11,12) returns 2 rows. Test case 3 is the same filter as test case 7 but just different column data types.

As a side note, the [`len`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) function also ignores trailing spaces, so 'Default ' with a space on the end returns a len of 7 instead of 8.  The [`datalength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function does include trailing spaces.

[image: test query results]

*the square brackets in the testval results above were only added to the query results to clearly show which testval had the space on the end, but the raw data does not have the square brackets.

Comment: The OP *doesn't* have trailing spaces on the **right** side (in the `LIKE`) though. They have them on the **left** side.

Comment: @ThomA I don't understand what you are trying to say. In the results of the =-query the trailing space is on the end of the Default-string.

Comment: *"When the right side of a LIKE predicate expression features a value with a trailing space"* `DC.ConfigurationName LIKE 'Default'` `'Default'` is on the *right*. `'Default ' LIKE 'Default'` is *true* not *false*. The behaviour the OP describes isn't [reproducible](https://dbfiddle.uk/AWtG_hC0).

Comment: @ThomA it is the same whether it is on the left or right side for the `LIKE` operator. `LIKE` matches exactly, but `=` does not.  Here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/500317/5

Comment: No, it isn't. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/th8YLgbY). `LIKE 'default'` returns *both* rows, `LIKE 'default '` returns 1. That is *not* the same behaviour. Your SQL Fiddle's behaviour is **wrong**. Your answer actually confirms it's wrong.

Comment: Interesting... using `varchar` data type on SQL 2022 the `LIKE` works differently and includes both results if right side does not have the space but only one result if right side does have the space.  But if I use `nvarchar` data type the right side has to match exactly.

Comment: @ThomA Here's an updated SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/922153/2  confirmed locally I get the same results on SQL 2022

Comment: DB Fiddle produces the expected results for both [`nvarchar`](https://dbfiddle.uk/0wKJR5Ml) and [`varchar`](https://dbfiddle.uk/CYXlvguG) even on 2014.

Answer (score 1):

According to section 8.2, General Rules, paragraph 3.a. in [the ANSI standard](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt):

> If the length in characters of X is not equal to the length in characters of Y, then the shorter string is effectively replaced, for the purposes of comparison, with a copy of itself that has been extended to the length of the longer string by concatenation on the right of one or more pad characters, where the pad character is chosen based on CS.

Therefore, what you see is the correct result for the equality comparison, since the string without the trailing space is padded for the comparison to match the string with the space.

The documented behavior for `LIKE` is defined in section 8.5, but it's much more complicated and harder to infer results for individual comparisons. The gist of it is the `LIKE` operator is also used for matching substrings within larger strings, and so it doesn't work to define the padding described in 8.2/GR/3a

Again, it's complicated, but the easiest place to understand it is 8.5, Generals rules, Part 5. This has sections `a)`, `b)`, and `c)`, where everything in either `a)` or `b)` must be true, or you get `c)`:

> Otherwise, M LIKE P is false.

In this case, `a)` only holds if both sides are 0 length, so clearly not true, and we find this in 5.b.v:

> [The predicate is true if there exists a partitioning of M into substrings such that:...] the number of substrings of M is equal to the number of substring specifiers of P.

But since you can take a substring to include the last trailing space from one side of the expression and not the other, this check cannot succeed for those strings.

Of course, this is the 92 standard, which is quite old now. However, later standards are not as easy to reference publicly<sup>*</sup> and the behaviors are similar.

Therefore we see the result for the `LIKE` comparison in the question also follows the standard.

---

<sup>* *fwiw, I'd **really** like to see the text of, say, [ANSI SQL-2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) make it's way to the public. That's old enough for ANSI to still derive meaningful revenue selling access to current standards, but would allow us to move things forward significantly in this kind of public discourse*</sup>